# wcf - creating datacontract

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

I've been tasked with writing a WCF service. (have not done this before.) I've received the xsd of the xml that I'll be receiveing and i'm trying to translate this into a datacontract. I require help though.

An example of a portion of the xml is:

```
<tfsChequeId xmlns="http://www.something.com/XMLSchemas/itrs/tfs/v1">
        <dic numericCode="20010411199194813505"/>
    </tfsChequeId>
```

What I've done so far is:

```
    [DataContract]
public class TFSChequeDic
{
    [DataMember]
    public string dic { get; set; }

}
```

How do I specify the numericCode attribute?

Any help would be gratefully received.

Kind Regards,
Fiona

**UPDATE**
A number of XSD's were provided to me. these are quite complex. On generating the datacontracts using svcutil.exe a number of errors were generated..
All of the following form:

```
Error: There was a validation error in the schemas provided for code generation:

Source:
Line: 85 Column: 6


Validation Error: Type 'http://www.something.com/XMLSchemas/itrs/common/v1:Docu
mentIdentifierCode' is not declared, or is not a simple type.
```

The generated datacontract is as follows:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="TfsChequeId", Namespace="http://www.something.com/XMLSchemas/itrs/tfs/v1")]
public partial class TfsChequeId : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{

    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    private www.something.com.XMLSchemas.itrs.tfs.v1.TfsChequeIdDic dicField;

    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public www.something.com.XMLSchemas.itrs.tfs.v1.TfsChequeIdDic dic
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dicField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dicField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

However I've no idea how to use this.. ie set numericCode?
Any ideas/hints/tips would be gratefully received.

Fiona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do it by hand. [SvcUtil](http://chakkaradeep.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/generating-wcf-proxy-using-svcutilexe/) will generate a client proxy for you if you feed it the WSDL. Or are you creating the service itself?

Comment: Thanks for that.. just after I posted I watched an online tutorial and discovered svcutil.exe and dc.exe. I will give that a go.. thanks again.

Comment: @Fiona:can you post the video url please

Comment: Here you go: http://www.microsoft.com/uk/msdn/screencasts/screencast/73/Windows-Communication-Foundation-DataContract-Serialization.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[xsd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** tool to create a class object from the xsd provided.